# delete dynamically added content when checkbox in popup.html is unchecked (manifest v3)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am injecting a JS file and CSS when a checkbox in popup.html is checked. This works.

```
    d.addEventListener("click", async () => {
    let [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({
        active: true,
        currentWindow: true
    });

    chrome.storage.local.set({
        landmarks: d.checked
    }, function () {

        if (d.checked) {

            try {
                chrome.scripting.insertCSS({
                    target: {
                        tabId: tab.id,
                        allFrames: true
                    },
                    files: ["css/show-alt-text.css"],
                });
            } catch (err) {
                console.error(`failed to insert CSS: ${err}`);
            }

            (async () => {
                const [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({
                    active: true,
                    currentWindow: true
                });
                try {
                    await chrome.scripting.executeScript({
                        target: {
                            tabId: tab.id,
                            allFrames: true
                        },
                        files: ["js/show-alt-text.js"],
                    });
                } catch (erri) {
                    console.error(`failed to execute script: ${erri}`);
                }
            })();

        } else {

            try {
                chrome.scripting.removeCSS({
                    target: {
                        tabId: tab.id,
                        allFrames: true
                    },
                    files: ["css/show-alt-text.css"],
                });
            } catch (err) {
                console.error(`failed to remove CSS: ${err}`);
            }

            document.querySelectorAll(".show-alt-text").forEach(altName => altName.remove());
        }
    });
});
```

The script loops through all the img elements on the page and positions a DIV with a class under each image:

Injected JS

```
const imgElements = document.querySelectorAll("img");
const showAltText = document.createElement("div");
showAltText.classList.add("show-alt-text");

for (let i = 0; i < imgElements.length; i++) {
    const altText = imgElements[i].alt;
    const element = showAltText.cloneNode(true);
    if (altText !== "") {
        element.innerHTML = "This image ALT text is: " + altText;
        imgElements[i].after(element);
    }
}
```

If the checkbox is unchecked the style sheet is removed. I also want to remove the injected DIV.

If I add the following JS to Chrome tools the DIV is removed.

```
document.querySelectorAll(".show-alt-text").forEach(altName => altName.remove());
```

However, if I use this in the else (unchecked) section of the popup.js, it does not work.

Can someone offer any help on getting this to work please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed

Don't declare as var, let or const.

imgElements = document.querySelectorAll("img");
showAltText = document.createElement("div");

Answer (score 0):

Using the same function as adding the script will remove the script

```
(async () => {
                const [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({
                    active: true,
                    currentWindow: true
                });
                try {
                    await chrome.scripting.executeScript({
                        target: {
                            tabId: tab.id,
                            allFrames: true
                        },
                        files: ["js/removeScript.js"],
                    });
                } catch (erri) {
                    console.error(`failed to execute script: ${erri}`);
                }
            })();
```

Comment: But this causes the function to only run once when the checkbox is checked/unchecked. If checked again the script has already run errors 'Identifier 'imgElements' has already been declared'. Back to square one.